# My cube goes through side walls on android device

Tags: unity, c#, 3d

I have a cube and it's on the ground and there are two walls (Plane) next to the ground. [image]

Like in the image there is a ground and in side there is a wall.
Here is my code:

```
    void Update() {

      transform.Translate(userDirection * speed * 14f * Time.deltaTime); 
    transform.Translate(mSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * 2 *  Time.deltaTime, 0f, mSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * 2 *  Time.deltaTime);


    if (Input.touchCount == 0)
        return;
    Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
    float originalY = transform.position.y;
    float cameraZ = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position).z;

    if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved || touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
        Vector3 screenPoint = new Vector3(touch.position.x, touch.position.y, cameraZ);
        Vector3 worldPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPoint);
        worldPoint.y = originalY;
        transform.position = worldPoint;
    }
}
```

My cube goes through the side walls, but on laptop it works perfectly, and on android device my cube goes through the side walls. Can anyone please tell why is my cube is going through side walls?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You shouldn't use Transform.translate to move the cube. Try to attach a rigidbody to the cube and move the cube using physics.

Comment: @GabrieleVierti I do have rigidbody attached to my cube

Comment: You see, now you are moving the cube against the walls, using Transform.translate . The problem is that both the cube and the wall collider don't want to pierce each other, so they try to apply forces on each other in order to stay separated. The cube to is STILL trying to go through the wall, and by doing this constantly, every frame, it is going to go through the wall. using a rigidbody things change: the rigidbody tries to go through the wall BUT, it encounters the collider. At this point the rigidbody stops going, and doesn't try to go through the wall, like Transform.translate does.

Comment: You do have a rigidbody on the cube, but you are not using it in your script. Right now it is just applying gravity on the cube object, but it is not moving it with your input.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: Here is a simple example from: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/roll-ball-tutorial/moving-player

Comment: @GabrieleVierti It looks to me like this would be worth posting as an Answer that can be marked accepted. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example on how to make the movement a lot smoother and more natural(this also solves the problem of the cube passing through the walls): https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/roll-ball-tutorial/moving-player

Answer (score 0):

Your cube is probably going through walls because your `Update()` method doesn't get called as often as it does on a laptop. The android device will most likely have something near 30 FPS and that means 30 calls to the update method. If your cube can move behind the plane in that time, then it will be counted as behind the plane.

You could use a 3D object like a cube instead of a plane to offset this. You could also just change the plane's collider to a cube collider and make it thicker so that your cube can't go through it. See badly drawn example below:

[image]

Of course, using built in physics will handle most of the work instead if you choose to go that route. It will also use the `FixedUpdate()` method and will behave the same way in all systems (or at least try to do so).